# CSS, Styling the Parent/Root but not the children? W/O creating sloppy CSS

Tags: html, css

So this is new, I'm trying to create clean CSS, here's my code example:

```
<ul id="Main">
 <li>blah blah</li>
 <li>blah blah</li>
 <li>blah blah</li>
 <li>
   <ul>
      <li>ding dong</li>
      <li>ding dong</li>
      <li>ding dong</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then I have the following CSS:

```
#Main li {
    background-color:Red;
}
```

Problem is I don't want the background-red in the DING DONG LI's is there a way in CSS to say not the root / children? Or do I need another ID/CLASS to cancel out the parent styling?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
#Main > li {
    background-color:Red;
}
```

`a > b` means that `b` is direct child of `a`

Comment: Well, the ding dong *is* in an `li` that is a direct child of `#Main`, so how does that help?

Comment: @TheApprentice Thanks, I might have misunderstood the questions. For this you do need "another ID/CLASS to cancel out the parent styling". (something like _meder_ mentioned, but with _background:white;_)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Main li { background:red; }
#Main li li { background:transparent; }
```

One could use `>` but it doesn't work in IE6. One could add additional `*` styles for IE6 but the above is arguably more succinct.